# Show convergence of an infinite sum by ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I would like to show that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^x|}$$ converges. I was hoping to do this by the ratio test, since we haven't covered the integral test yet so we are not allowed to use it.Trying the ratio test: $$\lim_{k \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{1}{|(n+1)^x|}}{\frac{1}{|n^x|}}} $$ Which simplifies to $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{|n^x|}{|(n+1)^x|}$$ However, I came out that the limit of this is 1, which would mean that the ratio test was non-conclusive.

Anyone have any thoughts towards an error I made, or if there is an easier way to prove this converges without the integral test? Thanks.

Comment: Take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity not as $x$ does. If $x \geq 1$ it does converge to a number in the range $(0,1)$. It might converge for other values also though.

Comment: Why do you need absolute value when $n \geq 1$?

Comment: @Nameless you could have imaginary $x$ that results in a negative number. Other than that there is no reason.

Comment: You can use the Cauchy Condensation Test. The main advantage is that it can be derived without a theory of integration.

Comment: He tagged "real analysis". But yes.

Comment: Actually that simplifies to $\left|\frac{n}{n+1}^x\right|$ which does go to $1$ sorry.

Comment: It should be $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ instead of $\lim_{k \to \infty}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas how would you apply the condensation test? That would be $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\frac{1}{|n^(2^n)|}$ right?

Comment: No, that would be $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \frac{1}{|(2^n)^x|}$. You can simplify this expression and then use the ratio test.

Comment: @VincentBoelens so that would simplify to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{|2^{nx}|}$, and then apply the ratio test?

Comment: @user137684 I'll assume $x$ is real and positive (you wouldn't be able to use Cauchy condensation otherwise), so we can do without the absolute value. Then the sum simplifies to $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n(x-1)}}$. Now use the ratio test.